# php select array value and pass it to another page

Tags: php, html, arrays, session, cookies

This will create one table.
Now, I want to pass the appointment_id & appointment_name which are array values, from this page by clicking generate prescription hyperlink to Second Page. And in Second page that passed values to patient id & patient name in `<value>` tag.

e.g,

```
id name type date       time     description  prescription

1. abc First 2017-04-08 11:35:00 body checkup Generate Prescription  

2. xyz First 2017-04-08 11:35:00 body checkup Generate Prescription
```

If I click on 2 then in second page I should get id as 2 & name as xyz.
But the problem is that it shows only last value of array and not the clicked one.

First Page

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($records, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

   echo "<tr>";

   echo "<td>"."<h3>".$result['appointment_id']."</h3>"."</td>";
    $_SESSION['session_patientid']=$result['appointment_id'];
   echo "<td>"."<h3>".$result['appointment_username']."</h3>"."</td>";
   $_SESSION['session_patientname']=$result['appointment_username'];
   echo "<td>"."<h3>".$result['appointment_type']."</h>"."</td>";
   echo "<td>"."<h3>".$result['date']."</h3>"."</td>";
   echo "<td>"."<h3>".$result['time']."</h3>"."</td>";
   echo "<td>"."<h3>".$result['message']."</h3>"."</td>";
   echo "<td>"."<h3>"."<a href='prescription.php'>".'Generate Prescription'."</a>"."</h3>"."</td>";
   echo "<br>";



   echo "</tr>";
 }
```

Second Page

```
<tr>
    <td>Patient ID : <br>
    </td>
    <td><input name="id" type="text" value="<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['session_patientid'])){echo $_SESSION['session_patientid'];}?>"><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Patient Name : <br>
    </td>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" value="<?PHP if(isset($_SESSION['session_patientname'])){echo $_SESSION['session_patientname'];}?>"><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION` overwrite the previous value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `while` loop each iteration overwrite `$_SESSION['session_patientid']` and `$_SESSION['session_patientname']`, only the last value will be saved. Pass the `patientid` and `patientname` in `url`, then in your second page you can use `$_GET` to get the id and name of the patient.

```
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($records, MYSQL_ASSOC))

    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>" . "<h3>" . $result['appointment_id'] . "</h3>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<h3>" . $result['appointment_username'] . "</h3>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<h3>" . $result['appointment_type'] . "</h>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<h3>" . $result['date'] . "</h3>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<h3>" . $result['time'] . "</h3>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<h3>" . $result['message'] . "</h3>" . "</td>";
    // pass the appointment id and appointment username in url, and access them using $_GET
    echo "<td>" . "<h3>" . "<a href='prescription.php?app_id=" . $result['appointment_id'] . "&pat_name=" . $result['appointment_username'] . "'>" . 'Generate Prescription' . "</a>" . "</h3>" . "</td>";
    echo "<br>";


    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Second page

```
<tr>
    <td>Patient ID : <br>
    </td>
    <td><input name="id" type="text" value="<?PHP if(isset($_GET['app_id'])){echo $_GET['app_id'];}?>"><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Patient Name : <br>
    </td>
    <td><input name="name" type="text" value="<?PHP if(isset($_GET['pat_name'])){echo $_GET['pat_name'];}?>"><br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
```